# What is the remainder when $2^{2016}+ 1009^{2016}$ is divided by $2019$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What is the remainder when $2^{2016} + 1009^{2016}$ is divided by $2019$?
The answer is $2$, but I am struggling to prove it.
Please help.

Comment: You're mentioning two different things in the title and the question. Which one is it?

Comment: @Arjun Banerjee still there are two different things; one is in the title and the other is in the body.

Comment: I can't understand which one the user wants. So I kept it as it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euler's theorem $$2^{1344} \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 2019).$$ Observe also by Euler's theorem that $$\begin{align*} 2^{672} &\equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 673).\end{align*}$$ and $$2^{672} \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 3)$$

So we have $$\begin{align*} 2^{672} & \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ \text {lcm}\ (3,673)). \\ & \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 2019). \end{align*}$$

Therefore $$\begin{align*} 2^{2016} & \equiv 2^{1344} \cdot 2^{672}\ (\text {mod}\ 2019). \\ & \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 2019). \end{align*}$$

Also by Euler's theorem we have $$1009^{1344} \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 2019)$$ and we also have $$1009^{672} \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 3)$$ and $$1009^{672} \equiv 1\  (\text {mod}\ 673).$$  So $$\begin{align*} 1009^{672} & \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ \text {lcm}\ (3,673)). \\ & \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 2019). \end{align*}$$

So $$\begin{align*} 1009^{2016} & \equiv 1009^{1344} \cdot 1009^{672}\ (\text {mod}\ 2019) \\ & \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 2019). \end{align*}$$

Now observe that $$\begin {align*} 2018^{2016} & \equiv (-1)^{2016}\ (\text {mod}\ 2019)\\ & \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 2019) \end{align*}$$

So we have $$2^{2016} + 1009^{2016} + 2018^{2016} \equiv 3\ (\text {mod}\ 2019).$$

Answer (score 0):

Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html,

$\lambda(2019)=$lcm$(2,672)=672$

If $(a,2019)=1,a^{672}\equiv1\pmod{2019}$

and $2016\equiv0\pmod{672}$

Comment: Carmichael function is not needed here. Repeated application of Euler's theorem will do the job.

Comment: @Dbchatto67, Carmichael function has been proved using repeated application of Euler's theorem, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Computing_'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000000A-QINU%60%22'_with_Carmichael's_theorem

Comment: Yeah. That's right. But when you can do something by hand why do you take help of other things?